# Copy only reference of item in Sitecore 6 tree structure

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have an item in Sitecore 6 backend containing all rendering and data to render itself. This item is a child of some other item in Sitecore tree structure.
So the tree looks like this:

```
Home 
  Parent Item
          My Item
  Another Parent Item
          I need a reference to My Item here
```

Is there a way to copy just a reference of the item? The idea is to have the same content with different url, but without copy/pasting. Because after a while content writer would like to change the content and he doesn't want to search for the copies and change them too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Sitecore 6.4 or later, you can accomplish this using clones.  Select the item to be copied, and then click the "Clone" button on the "Configure" ribbon.  The clone shows values from the original item, but also allows you to override them, at a field level, should the need arise.

For Sitecore 6.3 and earlier, you can use proxies. These do not allow the option of overiding fields, can lead to performance issues if used extensively, and have been deprecated with Sitecore 6.4.

You can learn more about both techniques at http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/reusing_and_sharing_data-a4.pdf and http://bit.ly/CloneTalk

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew the answer is simple, but wasn't able to find it.

Comment: I think the link that Dan provided has a typo(http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/reusing_and_sharing_data-a4.pdf**6/64/reusing_and_sharing_data-a4.pdf**), the document is here: [http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/reusing_and_sharing_data-a4.pdf](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/reusing_and_sharing_data-a4.pdf)

Comment: @Sarah Thanks, I fixed the original link as well.